# Is it an actual threat to system if "desktop" is added to path

Tags: virus, path, exploit

What kind of threat does adding the desktop path to system path variable present?
Is there some well known exploit that really opens my system up if I do this?
The thing is that Desktop is my downloads folder as well as my default workspace so I keep all my current projects as well as all the things I download.

I'm doing this because I'm a lazy person and would like to have my execs executable while I'm anywhere currently in my cmd

Comment: The biggest concern is ambiguity. invoke requests using the path, will always take the first path available for a given filename, which may or may not be the file you actually want to load. it could be an old version, or a malicious version, or a completely different program that is masquerading as the one you want to load. In the worst case, it just allows Trojans to trick the user.

Comment: Yeah, but as lpc said, the trojan does not really know about my specific case so it won't be working in such a way anyways, right?

Comment: its never a good idea to assume that a piece of malware isn’t smart enough to figure out how to hurt you. for instance, there is malware out there that hunts for dual boot systems and infects both OSes, even the offline instance. only about 1% of uses dualboot, but it was considered worth the trouble by the authors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you would answer that the more accessible a program is, the more risk it brings, and given that you use a download folder as a path would make it even more so. Even so, I would say that it won't really make a difference.

The reason is that when you download a program to your downloads folder, you have downloaded it in the first place. Secondly, the path will only be useful for executing programs and being able to find it. Malware and other kinds of programs that you would be afraid of, will not rely on the user having set their path like this, but instead create their own method to access the program by placing it in a folder that already would reside in the path variable.

So long story short, should not be seen as a security threat, but a general rule of thumb: with a system like that, don't get careless because careless actions result in doing things unintended. You'd become the security threat.